# running 4K display setup using GeForce 730/710 in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, 4k-resolution

I'm using LG 4K display and installed a GeForce 730 running on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. The performance is very bad. Just doing a task switch using alt-tab takes half a second to render between terminal and vscode. I changed resolution to full HD and only then it was working nicely.
I also have Nvidia Geforce 710 which is not installed on the MotherBoard.
My current display config output is shown below.

Please help me with these three questions:

1. Is there any solution to make my 4K display performance better using the this hardware?
2. Is there any way to  installed and configure the GeForce 710 to solve the problem?
3. What is the cheaper options for me to get a new GPU? or a ryzen cpu+gpu?

Thanks a lot.

### system

```
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64 
Host: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. TUF GAMING X570-PLUS (WI-FI) 
Kernel: 5.19.0-45-generic 
Uptime: 16 hours, 19 mins 
Packages: 3930 (dpkg), 33 (snap) 
Shell: zsh 5.8.1 
Resolution: 3840x2160 
DE: Plasma 5.24.7 
WM: KWin 
WM Theme: plastik 
Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: [Plasma], breeze [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
Terminal Font: AurulentSansM Nerd Font Mono 13 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 (12) @ 3.600GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 730 
Memory: 10238MiB / 64204MiB
```

### sudo hwinfo --gfxcard

```
10: PCI 900.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)             
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: x1VA.qyqR+_AjaL8
  Parent ID: w+J7.93wBZi3uma4
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:09:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:09:00.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "nVidia GK208B [GeForce GT 730]"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x1287 "GK208B [GeForce GT 730]"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1043 "ASUSTeK Computer Inc."
  SubDevice: pci 0x881a 
  Revision: 0xa1
  Driver: "nvidia"
  Driver Modules: "nvidia"
  Memory Range: 0xfb000000-0xfbffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xe0000000-0xe7ffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xe8000000-0xe9ffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xe000-0xefff (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 115 (2068210 events)
  I/O Ports: 0x3c0-0x3df (rw)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd00001287sv00001043sd0000881Abc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: nvidiafb is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidiafb"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: nouveau is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nouveau"
  Driver Info #2:
    Driver Status: nvidia_drm is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidia_drm"
  Driver Info #3:
    Driver Status: nvidia is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidia"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #7 (PCI bridge)

Primary display adapter: #10
```

### inxi -G

```
    Graphics:
      Device-1: NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 730] driver: nvidia v: 470.182.03
      Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
        unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia resolution: 3840x2160
      OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GT 730/PCIe/SSE2
        v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.182.03
```

### xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +  59.94    50.00*   30.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    23.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an entry-level graphical card, not meant for doing great graphics.

If you look at the average performance note from 3DMARK :

- [NVIDIA GeForce GT 730](https://www.3dmark.com/search?_ga=2.187445864.1111626879.1688117046-433350036.1688117046#advanced?test=pcm10b%20D&cpuId=&gpuId=973&gpuCount=0&gpuType=ALL&deviceType=ALL&storageModel=ALL&memoryChannels=0&country=&scoreType=overallScore&hofMode=false&showInvalidResults=false&freeParams=&minGpuCoreClock=&maxGpuCoreClock=&minGpuMemClock=&maxGpuMemClock=&minCpuClock=&maxCpuClock=) :
  2714
- [NVIDIA GeForce GT 710](https://www.3dmark.com/search?_ga=2.187445864.1111626879.1688117046-433350036.1688117046#advanced?test=pcm10b%20D&cpuId=&gpuId=1091&gpuCount=0&gpuType=ALL&deviceType=ALL&storageModel=ALL&memoryChannels=0&country=&scoreType=overallScore&hofMode=false&showInvalidResults=false&freeParams=&minGpuCoreClock=&maxGpuCoreClock=&minGpuMemClock=&maxGpuMemClock=&minCpuClock=&maxCpuClock=)
  : 2751
- [Intel HD Graphics 510](https://www.3dmark.com/search?_ga=2.187445864.1111626879.1688117046-433350036.1688117046#advanced?test=pcm10b%20D&cpuId=&gpuId=1081&gpuCount=0&gpuType=ALL&deviceType=ALL&storageModel=ALL&memoryChannels=0&country=&scoreType=overallScore&hofMode=false&showInvalidResults=false&freeParams=&minGpuCoreClock=&maxGpuCoreClock=&minGpuMemClock=&maxGpuMemClock=&minCpuClock=&maxCpuClock=)
  : 2247

You can see that the GT 710/730 have basically the same performance
as that of the Intel Integrated Graphics.

NVIDIA model number follow in general this schema :

```
x30 = Entry
x50 = Entry level gaming
x60 = Mid range gaming
x70 = High end gaming
x80 = Enthusiast
```

A higher-performance card model would improve your graphical performance, but better check first its real performance numbers
on 3DMARK.

Interesting reading :
[GT 730 FPS issue (underperforming)](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/gt-730-fps-issue-underperforming.220256/).